# ipyleaflet heatmap intensity not reflecting correctly

Tags: python, jupyter, heatmap

Say I have a list of 5 locations with coordinates, and each location has a number I want to show on a heatmap, so I can visualize which loation has most 'hits'. For example

```
Location 1: x,y,80

Location 2: x,y,1

Location 3: x,y,20

Location 4: x,y,40

Location 5: x,y,30
```

I’m creating the heatmap by adding the location to the heatmap with the intensity set to the number of times the count is, so

```
heatmapLocations = []
for location in locations
                heatmapLocations.append((x,y,count))
heatmap = Heatmap(locations=heatmapLocations)
```

My heatmap is showing, and it shows the highest count as a red circle, so that’s correct, also location 3 with count 20 is shown as light yellow, which is also correct, but location 4 and 5 are shown the same as location 1, especially when I zoom in, as if they have the same density, although there value is half of location 1. How can I reflect this? I tried the different heatmap parameters as max_zoom, radius, etc, but can’t seem to get it right.

Comment: By the way I'm using ipyleaflet version 0.13.3